# Nested if the condition is not working

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. I have a column in the database like

```
id | list_id |venue_id |name | start_date | end_date |start_time | end_time
```

Now I have a form with fields are

```
<select name="venue_id[]">// this can be multiple section
<option value="1">qwer</option>
<option value="2">poiu</option>
<option value="3">tgred</option>            
</select
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" name="start_date" placeholder="Start Date" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" name="end_date" placeholder="End Date" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" name="start_time" placeholder="start time" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" name="end_time" placeholder="End time" class="datepicker">
```

Now What I am doing is, In case if there is no data in the database then the user enter all the information and click on submit then data will insert in the database.

Now lets us assume that the data user enters the first time

```
 id | list_id |venue_id |name | start_date | end_date |start_time | end_time 
 1  |1        | 2       |xyz  |2018-08-18  |2018-08-30|5:00AM     |8:00AM
```

Now if user want to insert again then first It should check in the database that

```
 if(venue_id is same or not)// if not same then insert the data. if the same than checks date
 if(check start_date and end_date)
  // in case both are same or between then it will check the start_time and end_time should not be same or between or else insert data.

 if (time is matching or between the from 5:00 am to 8:00 am then display the error message)

  else(time not matching then insert a new record)
```

I am trying above logic to handle my issue but it's not working. anyone know about better logic in this please let me know.

**controller code**

```
         $id                         = $this->input->post('venue_id');
            $venue_id                   = implode(',',$id);     
            $activity_list_id           = $this->input->post('activity_name');
            $new_batch_start_date       = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('start_date')));    
            $new_batch_end_date         = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('end_date')));
            $new_batch_start_time       = $this->input->post('start_time');
            $new_batch_end_time         = $this->input->post('end_time');

        if($new_batch_start_date>= $new_batch_end_date)
            {
              $response['error'] = false;
              $response['msg']   = "End Date Should be Greater than Start Date";
              echo json_encode($response);
              return false;
            }

        $data=array(//insert data);
        $get_batch_details = $this->Batch_model->fetchBatches(); // 
        if(!empty($get_batch_details))
            {
              foreach ($get_batch_details as $rows)
              {
                $exist_batch_start_date =  $rows->start_date;
                $exist_batch_end_date =  $rows->end_date;
                $batch_time1 =  strtotime($rows->start_time);
                $batch_time2 =  strtotime($rows->end_time);
                $batch_venue_id = explode(',',$rows->batch_venue_id);
                $common_venue_id = array_intersect($id,$batch_venue_id);
               if($common_venue_id)
                {
             if($exist_batch_start_date <= $new_batch_start_date && $exist_batch_end_date >= $new_batch_start_date )
    {
     if($batch_time1 <= $new_batch_start_time && $batch_time2 > $new_batch_start_time){

          $msg = "Please Change Time Slot or Start And End Date. It's already booked"; 
          $response['error'] = false;
          $response['msg']   = $msg;
         break;
        }
        }
        }
else 
    {
      $result = $this->Batch_model->createBatch($data);
       if ($result) {
         $response['error'] = true;
         $response['msg']   = "Batch Created";
      }
        }
        }
        else 
            {
              $result = $this->Batch_model->createBatch($data);
              if ($result) {
                 $response['error'] = true;
                 $response['msg']   = "Batch Created";
              }
              echo json_encode($response);
```

Ajax

```
success: function(response)
            {
             var data = JSON.parse(response);
             if (data.error == true)
             { //some code here} 
             else {//some code here}
            }
```

As per Gaurav Genius suggested answer. I tried

```
  $get_batch_details = $this->Batch_model->fetchBatches(); 
    if(!empty($get_batch_details))
    {
      foreach ($get_batch_details as $rows)
      {
        $exist_batch_start_date =  $rows->start_date;
        $exist_batch_end_date =  $rows->end_date;
        echo $batch_time1 =  strtotime($rows->start_time);
        echo $batch_time2 =  strtotime($rows->end_time);
        $batch_venue_id = explode(',',$rows->batch_venue_id);
        $common_venue_id = array_intersect($id,$batch_venue_id);

if($common_venue_id == $venue_id && ($new_batch_start_date < $new_batch_end_date && $new_batch_start_date >= $exist_batch_start_date && $new_batch_end_date <= $exist_batch_end_date) && 
($new_batch_start_time < $new_batch_end_time && $new_batch_start_time >= $batch_time1 && $new_batch_end_time >= $batch_time2))
  {
  $msg = "Please Change Time Slot or Start And End Date"; 
  $response['error'] = false;
   $response['msg']   = $msg;
   print_r($response);
}else{
      $result = $this->Batch_model->createBatch($data);
      if ($result) {
         $response['error'] = true;
         $response['msg']   = "Batch Created";
      }
}
echo json_encode($response);
      }
    }
else 
    {
      $result = $this->Batch_model->createBatch($data);
      if ($result) {
         $response['error'] = true;
         $response['msg']   = "Batch Created";
      }
  }
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Did you forget opening and closing brackets for IF blocks { } ? or this is a sample description?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour, Nope, I tried some code which I shared. Might be I forgot to add in the question. But thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 0):

You can build logic like this...conditions you can modify according to your need...

```
if(database.venue_id == form.venue_id && (form.start_date < form.end_date && form.start_date >= database.start_date && form.end_date <= database.end_date) && 
(form.start_time < form.end_time && form.start_time ......)){
    //show error;
}else{
    //insert record;
}
```

**OR** If you want to give customize error message for each validation...

use nested, if..elseif...elseif...elseif....else

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Give me some time to implement you answer

Comment: you have to build conditions according to your need, you need to debug conditions, which one passed which one failed etc

Comment: if($common_venue_id == $venue_id && ($new_batch_start_date < $new_batch_end_date && $new_batch_start_date >= $exist_batch_start_date && $new_batch_end_date <= $exist_batch_end_date) && 
($new_batch_start_time < $new_batch_end_time && $new_batch_start_time >= $batch_time1 && $new_batch_end_time >= $batch_time2)){
  $msg = "Please Change Time Slot or Start And End Date"; 
  $response['error'] = false;
   $response['msg']   = $msg;
}else{$result = $this->Batch_model->createBatch($data);if ($result) {$response['error'] = true;$response['msg']   = "Created";}}
echo json_encode($response);

Comment: I tried above code as per your logic. Please check it once. if it is correct or not

Comment: what did you get, error or data is being inserted? whether if is being executed or else?

Comment: I updated my code in the question. IF there is no record in the data and data are inserting. but after that If I tried your logic but it's not working.

Comment: @user9437856, what error / message did you get? I means which block executed if or else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178242/discussion-between-gaurav-genius-and-user9437856).